# How to increase maximum concurrent jobs?

Tags: jenkins

In my newly installed `Jenkins`, I have four jobs. I can only run two concurrently. If I trigger the build of a third job, it is set in the queue and triggered once one of the first two finishes.

I know my server can handle more than two concurrent jobs at a time. How can I increase this default threshold of two?

If it means anything, these are not build-a-deployable package kind of jobs but environment prep jobs that instantiate various DBs. So the jobs simply invoke a python script on the Jenkins server, which is the same script across multiple jobs but each job invokes it with different input params. The jobs are 100% independent of one another and do not share any resource except the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You go to `Manage Jenkins --> Configure System`, then change `# of executors`:

[image]